# Is there a VB.NET plugin for CodeRay (or any VB.NET syntax highlighting)?

Tags: vb.net, syntax-highlighting, redmine, coderay

I recently set up a [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) server for my time. Redmine's Wiki uses [CodeRay](http://coderay.rubychan.de/) for syntax highlighting. However, most of my team prefers to code in VB.NET, which CodeRay doesn't support.

Are there any plugins out there that offer syntax highlighting for VB.NET in CodeRay? If not in CodeRay, maybe through some other library (that could be integrated into Redmine)?

Answer (score 0):

There is no VB scanner yet. However, you can use [Pygments with Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/issues/1651), which has support for a load of languages.

Answer (score 0):

Also see the Ultraviolet plugin information http://www.redmine.org/plugins/redmine_ultraviolet